# TYPO3 9 - wrong url to homepage

Tags: typo3-9.x

In my fluid template I have

`{f:uri.page(pageUid:'{uid}')}`

It works fine except for main page - it results with url like mydomain.com/.html

Below there is basic Routing configuration:

```
rootPageId: 1
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: .html
    index: ''
    map:
      .html: 0
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435`
```

I would expect link to homepage is just mydomain.com (and not for example mydomain.com/index.html) but I can not make it work in routing in TYPO3 9.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the .html: 0 line in your code. For me this works

```
  PageTypeSuffix:
   type: PageType
   default: /
   index: ''
   map:
    /: 0
```

In the Base Language Part check if base equals `/`